# Find a matrix that represents the dynamic system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

I just don't really understand how to do this problem at all. I think it's a dynamic systems problem and A is just asking me to find a system of equations, but it's the time variable that is throwing me off. What would the rows and columns of this new matrix even be? What does the condition mean?

It would be great if I could get a step-by-step explanation.

[image: Question]

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h_t$ and $m_t$ denote the number of healthy and sick fish in year number $t$ respectively.

According to the provided information, $70$% of the healthy fish duplicate, $20%$% become sick, and $10$% die in one year. This implies $70$% of the healthy fish in year $t$ remain alive and healthy for year $t+1$. Taking into account the $3$ additional healthy fish that migrate into the lake from abroad, we determine the following formula for $h_{t+1}$: $$h_{t+1}=(0.7)h_t+(0.7)h_t+3=1.4h_t+3$$

Since $20$% of the healthy fish in year $t$ become sick in year $t+1$ while all the sick fish in year $t$ die off, we see that  $m_{t+1}=0.2h_t$ and so $$\begin{pmatrix}h_{t+1}\\ m_{t+1}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1.4h_t+3\\ 0.2h_t\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1.4&0&3\\ 0.2&0&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_t\\ m_t\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Diagonalizing yields a more attractive dynamical system. $$\begin{pmatrix}h_{t+1}\\ m_{t+1}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-15&7\\ 1&-3&1\\ 0&2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&\frac{7}{5}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{7}&1&\frac{3}{7}\\ 0&0&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{7}&0&\frac{15}{14}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_t\\ m_t\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ Taking $\begin{pmatrix}h_0\\ m_0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}100\\ 20\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ reveals $$\begin{eqnarray*}\begin{pmatrix}h_t\\ m_t\\ 1\end{pmatrix} &=& \begin{pmatrix}0&-15&7\\ 1&-3&1\\ 0&2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{7}&1&\frac{3}{7}\\ 0&0&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{7}&0&\frac{15}{14}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}100\\ 20\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\\ &=&\begin{pmatrix}0&-15&7\\ 1&-3&1\\ 0&2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{83}{7}\\ \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{215}{14}\end{pmatrix} \\ &=&\begin{pmatrix}0&-15&7\cdot \left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^t\\ 0&-3&\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^t\\ 0&2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{83}{7}\\ \:\frac{1}{2}\\ \:\frac{215}{14}\end{pmatrix} \\ &=& \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{15}{2}+\frac{215}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^t\\ -\frac{3}{2}+\frac{215}{14}\cdot \left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^t\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$$ Take $t\longrightarrow +\infty$ to see the result.

Comment: Thank you so much for this !! Exactly what I needed